# 16bit multiplier vhdl code synthesize error

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, modelsim, xilinx-ise, synthesize

I want to write a 16bit * 16bit multiplication code. Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity mul is
   port
   (
      A, B: IN INTEGER RANGE -32768 TO 32767;

      C: OUT INTEGER RANGE -2147483648 TO +2147483647
   );
end mul;

architecture Behavioral of mul is
begin

   C <= A * B;

end behavioral;
```

But when I'm trying to sythesize the code on xilinx isim I get this error:

ERROR:Bitgen:342 - This design contains pins which have locations (LOC) that are
not user-assigned or I/O Standards (IOSTANDARD) that are not user-assigned.
This may cause I/O contention or incompatibility with the board power or
connectivity affecting performance, signal integrity or in extreme cases
cause damage to the device or the components to which it is connected.  To
prevent this error, it is highly suggested to specify all pin locations and
I/O standards to avoid potential contention or conflicts and allow proper
bitstream creation.  To demote this error to a warning and allow bitstream
creation with unspecified I/O location or standards, you may apply the
following bitgen switch: -g UnconstrainedPins:Allow
ERROR:Bitgen:157 - Bitgen will terminate because of the above errors.

Comment: You are supposed to assign the entity ports to a FPGA pin using ucf

Comment: Why are you duplicating questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510544/two-signed-numbers-multplication-synthesize-io-error

Comment: If it got as far as Bitgen you don't have a synthesis error. Just allocate appropriate I/O pins and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ports defined in the entity should have a pin assignment defined using ucf file. If you are missing an ucf file, the tool will go ahead and place the pins by itself. This is clearly stated in the error message.

```
NET"A(0)"                LOC ="AB16"       | IOSTANDARD ="LVTTL";
NET"A(1)"                LOC ="AB16"       | IOSTANDARD ="LVTTL";
...
```

In your example, the width of A & B is 16 bits and C is 32 bits. So you need to assign correct pin location and IO standard for all of them.